# Is using a singleton as a data manager class bad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

I commonly create apps that require storage of data, and this data is used across the entire program. It's not much, though, so I usually use `NSUserDefaults` to load/save this data. However, the saving/loading code, along with packing/unpacking the data, takes up space, and I thought moving this code to reusable methods inside a global singleton would be a good idea. It seems to have worked well.

Even so, I've read a lot lately on the evils of singletons and global objects, and I've started to have second thoughts. People often say that the use of singletons is almost always an indications of poor design. For the most part, I'd disagree (I think simple uses like this are a good design pattern), but I'm certainly no expert on the matter.

So, is using singletons even in a simple way like this bad? If so, what's the better alternative?

Comment: No, not bad, not bad at all.  Keep in mind that a number of iOS SDK classes provided by Apple are implemented as singletons.  Which isn't to say that Apple code is automatically good code, but it does strongly imply that the singleton pattern isn't without redeeming qualities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I definitely don't agree that singletons are evil. They are sometimes overused perhaps but on some occasions are just perfect for the job. In some applications it makes sense to have some kind of general data manager. The singleton pattern is used extensively in the SDK itself (app delegates, shared managers, default centers and so on). Most often these are not "pure" singletons, as in you can access a shared instance but can also create new instances if necessary.

The question you need to ask yourself is whether it would be useful to have access to a single instance of a data manager from anywhere at anytime, if it isn't then a singleton is probably not needed. If you are going to be using singletons in multi-threaded environments however, you do need to worry about race conditions (can one thread modify a resource while another is accessing it), the documentation has good explanations on how best to achieve this in Cocoa.

Let me try to explain with an example - Am using some code from a game I wrote. Let's say you have a `GameMap` class and a `Tile` class.  The `GameMap` represents a 2 dimension grid of `Tile` objects.

```
GameMap *gameMap = [[GameMap alloc] init];
NSArray *theTiles = gameMap.tiles;
```

The instance of the `GameMap` owns the grid of tiles, and creates the tiles when the game map is created.  No singleton needed.

You may say "but I only have one `GameMap` at a time, what's the big deal?".  What about loading saved games, or loading new levels?  Well that becomes as easy as:

```
// In whatever class object owns the game map
self.gameMap = [[GameMap alloc] initWithSaveData:saveData];
```

In conclusion, create an instance of a class that has code to manage other instances of things. Keep as little global as possible and your code will be more scalable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, that's generally my opinion on things as well. I just needed a bit on confirmation that the singleton pattern was not all evil, since after all the reading I've done on them, it sounded a bit like they were something to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: well, glad to help. i have made my case above. Its like this right, alcohol is supposedly bad for health but it fine to drink in moderation. Same thing here.